# How can I disable or delete Gnome lock screen?

Tags: gnome, screen, lock

How can I disable or delete Gnome lockscreen? I mean, actually, I don't like Gnome display a wallpaper and a big clock after lock screen. Can I just have a login screen instead? Thanks everyone to have a look my question and give me advice!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Go into the `Activates`.

Then type `settings`.

`Click` on the icon that has a `spanner and a screwdriver` and says `Settings` .

When it has opened, `click` on the icon that looks like a `lock dial` and says `Privacy`.

`Click` on the item that says `Screen Lock`.

`Click` on the `toggle switch` next the text that says `Automatic Screen Lock`.

`Press` the button that says `Close`.

The item that says `Screen Lock` should have `Off` next to it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that but it doesn't work for my question. Because I want disable lock screen with wallpaper and a big clock, and just display the login screen.