# Can't unlock gnome desktop on ubuntu 20.04 via VNC, but it gets unlocked when I unlock the screen on console screen

Tags: server, 20.04, gnome, lock-screen, tightvncserver

A strange thing is happening.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and usually I use VNC from my Windows 20 machine to access the Ubuntu machine.
When the screen is locked on the VNC, when I entered the password, the screen is not unlocked. It is stuck there. But in this state, when I lock the screen on console GNOME and unlock it, the GNOME window that was in locked state on the VNC window is also unlocked.

I have changed the static IP address of the Ubuntu machine today. Actually switched to DHCP mode once. Can it be related to this IP address setting? What can I do to avoid this problem?

I don't know this is relevant, but I find occasional message windows saying 'Chan Kim will be automatically logget out in 60 seconds' while I use the machine through VNC. I just click cancel.

Answer (score 0):

Lock screen in Gnome doesn't work for VNC. You need to disable it.

What you need to do is:

1. Reboot (or otherwise unlock).
2. Go into the **Activates** → **Settings** (cog icon).
3. Go to **Privacy** tab.
4. Go to **Screen Lock**.
5. Toggle *off* a **Automatic Screen Lock** switch.

Close the settings and you are good to go.

See also: [How can I disable or delete Gnome lock screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/694313/how-can-i-disable-or-delete-gnome-lock-screen)

BTW. There is a 10 year old bug in the gnome lock screen: [Bug 960149 - unable to unlock gnome in ThinLinc (VNC)](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=960149). So that doesn't seem like something that will be fixed any time soon